# How often does the Mertens function vanish?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, elementary-proofs, mobius-inversion

It is well known that the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function)

$$M(x)=\sum _{n\leq x}\mu(n)$$

has infinitely many zeros, and this seems to be a [short proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2345591/109021).

**Are there known results about *how often* the Mertens function is 0?** (i.e. how many times on average between $1$ and $x$)

Also, is it possible to prove that it vanishes infinitely often with elementary techniques only, and no complex analysis / Zeta function? (In the same way the PNT has been proved elementary by Selberg/Erdös around 1950).

Comment: Regarding your second question: we can start by asking whether there is an elementary proof of classical oscillation theorems, for example that $\psi(x)-x$ changes sign infinitely often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting an answer to the question [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273845/oscillation-of-the-summatory-möbius-function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273845/oscillation-of-the-summatory-m%C3%B6bius-function)

> Let  $c=14.1347251…$. Then there are at least $(c/\pi-o(1))\log y$ sign changes in $M(x)$ in the interval $[1,y]$. This was proved by Kaczorowski and Pintz (Acta Math. Hungar. 48 (1986), 173-185, doi 10.1007/BF01949062).

This may well be the state of the art, but any comments on further results would of course be welcome. If no more is known then this question is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: I guess c is the imaginary part of the first non trivial zero of zeta ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, nothing stronger than $\Omega(\log y)$ is known for the number of sign changes of any of the usual number-theoretic functions and their error terms. Even showing that the number of sign changes grows faster than any constant multiple of $\log y$ seems quite difficult. Daniel Fiorilli pointed out in his thesis that one of the reasons we can't do better (despite the truth probably being around $\sqrt y$) is that these proofs use a many-times-averaged version of these functions, which actually do have only $O(\log y)$ sign changes.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, yes. Basj, I will see if I can track down a PDF.

Comment: @Basj, how can I get the PDF to you? I don't have a webpage I can upload to.

Comment: @kodlu Interesting article, that uses complex analysis techniques. Do you know if there are elementary techniques that can prove the same thing?

Comment: Teaching you to fish:  :)  Typing "Fiorilli" into [The Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu) uncovers the title of his thesis, *Irrégularités dans la distribution des nombres premiers et des suites plus générales dans les progressions arithmétiques*; the first Google hit gets you the PDF. It definitely uses complex methods, specifically the explicit formula.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Wrong, kept for the comments below.

I'm trying an answer with an elementary argument:

Let's assume there exists $A > 0$ such that $M(x) \neq 0$ for $x \geq A$.
We can assume that $M(x) \geq 1$ for $x \geq A$, as the proof would be the same in the negative case. Let:

$$K = \sum_{k \leq A} |M(k)|.$$

Then the well-known identity

$$1 = \sum_{d \leq x} M(x/d)$$

gives 
$$1 = \left|\sum_{d \leq x/A} M(x/d) + \sum_{x/A < d\leq x} M(x/d)\right|\geq \sum_{d \leq x/A} M(x/d)-K \geq \lfloor{x/A}\rfloor -K \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]\, +\infty$$

which is a contradiction.

As a conclusion, the Mertens function $M(x)$ has infinitely many zeros.

I wonder if a similar (but more clever) elementary argument can lead to an estimation of *how often* the Mertens function vanishes between $1$ and $y$.

Comment: The estimate is wrong, because each of the values of $M(k)$ is included many times. For example, take $A=2$. Then $K=1$, but $\sum_{x/2<d\le x}M(x/d)=x/2$.

Comment: My bad, that's right... Do you think there's a way to fix this @EmilJeřábek? Because repetitions of $M(x/d)$ in $\sum_{d\leq x} M(x/d)$ only seem to appear when $x/d < \sqrt x$.

Comment: $\sum_{d \le x} M(x/d) = \sum_{n \in (\sqrt{x},x]} M(n)+\sum_{n \le \sqrt{x}} M(n) (\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{x}{n+1} \rfloor)$, then see what you get with $M(n)=n^{\sigma}$, that the second sum is not small is one of the main difficulty for the RH. Looking instead at $\sum_{d \le x} M(x/d)(-1)^d$ means $\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor\bmod 2$. Anyway to estimate the number of sign changes you should start with the density of zeros and an effective explicit formula such as $\psi(x)-x-\log 2\pi = \sum_{|Im(\rho)| < T} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}+ \mathcal{O}(x^{1/2} \log^2x/T)$ (under the RH)

Comment: @reuns Thank you. I have already looked at complex methods / involving zeros of zeta function, etc., but here I was curious if there could be a fully elementary method. So do you mean fixing my (wrong) argument in this answer is hopeless?

Comment: The key of the (elementary) argument in my linked answer is that $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic with no zeros on $(0,\infty)$ (not only that the coefficients of $\zeta(s)$ are close to $1$,), and that $M(x)$ stays non-negative for $x > N$ would imply $1/\zeta(s)$ has a singularity at $\sigma$ its abscissa of convergence,  so your argument should use it

Comment: I don't see how you could fix that. For constant $A$, $\sum_{x/A<d\le x}M(x/d)=c_Ax+O(1)$ where $c_A$ is a (usually nonzero) constant depending on $A$, and all your argument shows is that, assuming $M$ does not change sign infinitely often, $|c_A|\ge1/A$ for all sufficiently large $A$. This is likely even harder to disprove than the original assumption.

Comment: You're right @reuns: $\sum_{n \le \sqrt{x}} |M(n)| (\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{x}{n+1} \rfloor) \gg x$ even if we took $|M(n)| \ll n^{1/2+\epsilon}$ (that would require RH...). Something else: what did you mean with $\sum_{d \le x} M(x/d)(-1)^d$ and $\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor\bmod 2$?

Comment: $-1=\sum_{d \le x} M(x/d) (-1)^{d+1} = \sum_{n \in (\sqrt{x},x]} M(n)(-1)^{x+n} +\sum_{n \le \sqrt{x}} M(n) (\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\rfloor-\lfloor \frac{x}{n+1} \rfloor \bmod 2)$ for $x \ge 2$

Comment: Good to know @reuns. Do you think this could help to find an elementary argument? (better than my wrong answer here!)

Comment: ?? My answer on MSE is elementary. I don't think elementary arguments can count the number of zeros crossings, that's why i mentioned the explicit formula

Comment: MSE (Mathematics Stack Exchange) is what @reuns is referring to.

Comment: Oh you mean [this proof on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2345591/109021) (that I linked in my question), I forgot it was yours @reuns ;)